# LINQ to SQL calling stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to connect to SQL stored procedure using LINQ. It works pretty good for stored procedures that have static SQL query.

I want to connect to a stored procedure that has dynamic SQL.

At the end of stored procedure it has an `exec` statement.

```
exec(@srchQuery)
```

When I do that it doesn't work because it is dynamic SQL.

If I use `print @srchQuery` and copy that stored procedure and use that static SQL in stored procedure, it works with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL analyses the direct `SELECT` statements to see what model type it has to project as the result of executing said SQL stored procedure. Because you are using a dynamic statement using `EXEC`, it can't determine what model type to generate.

Simple answer would be to either not use a Stored Procedure, and instead use LINQ to SQL to generate the SQL, or don't use a dynamic built statement within your stored procedure.

The fact that you are generating a SQL statement must mean you have a strong use case for it, as it can achieve what you want without a stored procedure. Always favour simplicity... ask yourself, do you *need* to use a dynamically built statement *within* a stored procedure?

Comment: Simplicity is good thing but I need to use dynamically built statement within a stored procedure. I could probably use Table Variable in T-SQL. But, I am not too familiar in that domain. Have anyone used table variable and make it work or know a logic that might work?

Comment: @Bfree answer worked. There's no real easy way to do this. I've had the same problem in the past. I think the issue is that Linq to Sql has no way of "figuring out" which type will be returned since you're building up the SELECT statement at execution time. What I did to get around this, was in the stored proc, I did just a select and selected all the columns that I possibly needed. Then, I had Linq to Sql generate the function based on that. Then, I went back to SQL and changed the stored proc back to the way it's supposed to be. The trick here is not to regenerate your DBML.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the stored procedure directly within the DataContext:

```
using (YourDataContext dc = new YourDataContext())
{
    ...
    dc.ExecuteCommand("EXEC MyStoredProcedure");
    ...
}
```

Comment: will this still map as a linq result set?

Comment: No, there will be no resultset. The stored procedure execution will result in an integer value being output.